# JMETER Performance Testing - Dynamic Payload

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter, performance-testing

While doing performance testing via JMETER, I encountered one usecase where the POST request call is taking the dynamic data from the website. So in that case when we run our script it fails as that data is no more available on the website.

Payload looks like given below. It is a POST CALL and the payload is changing everytime.

{"marketId":"U-16662943","price":{"up":98,"down":100,"dec":"1.98"},"side":"HOME","line":0,"selectionids":["W2-1"]}

Could anyone suggest how we can make this payload dynamic when we create a script in JMETER?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of 3 possible options:

1. Duplicate data is not allowed. If this is the case you can use JMeter Functions like [__Random()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random), [__RandomString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomString), [__counter()](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-counter-jmeter-test/) and so on
2. The data you're sending needs to be aligned with the data in the application somehow, in this case you can use [JDBC PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_PreProcessor) in order to build a proper request body basing on the data from the application under test database
3. The data is present in previous response. In that case it's a matter of simple [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start), the dynamic values should be extracted from the previous response using suitable [Post-Processors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) and variables needs to be sent instead of hard-coded parameters